# SpringMVC : POST Redirect GET and error message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a page with a form and a table. When i submit the form, i want it to fill the table.

I tried simply returning the view name, but it doesn't go through the "Get" method.

I saw the Post Redirect Get pattern so i tried it, and it effectively refresh the page like it should. But then the validation errors aren't shown in the  tags.

I saw elsewhere that you can use RedirectAttributes and flashAttribute the bindingResult, but it's still not working.

I don't know what is the normal way of doing this thing.

Here's my code :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/settings")
public class SettingsController {
    @Autowired
    protected SettingsService settingsService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void loadSettings(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("settings", new Settings());
        model.addAttribute("settingsList", settingsService.getAllSettings();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveSettings(@ModelAttribute("settings") @Valid Settings settings, Errors errors, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
       // code

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("settings", settings);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.settings", errors);
        return "redirect:/settings";
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/9329741/217324 ?

Comment: It's the same question but the answer is a hack, and that means it's not the "normal way" intended by spring. Since spring-mvc 1 we have to post and then show the result. How can it still be so complicated to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work, but i have NO idea why :

Instead of this :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void loadSettings(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("settings", new Settings());
        model.addAttribute("settingsList", settingsService.getAllSettings();
    }
```

I have this :

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void loadSettings(Model model) {
        if (!model.containsAttribute("settings")) {
          model.addAttribute("settings", new Settings());
        }
        model.addAttribute("settingsList", settingsService.getAllSettings();
    }
```

And it works, but the form keeps the data posted. It's one or the other :/